# Почему не ставится заголовок в xhr

Tags: javascript, yii2, reactjs, xhr

Есть апи написанное на Yii2, при запросе через Rest клиент с заголовком Authorization всё отрабатывает как надо.

При запросе через xhr из яваскрипт приложения, не ставится заголовок, yii его не видит. Не могу понять в чем проблема

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://myhost.loc/post?startDate=01.10.2017&endDate=30.11.2017', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1...');
    xhr.send();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState != 4) return;
        if (this.status != 200) {
            alert( 'ошибка: ' + (this.status ? this.statusText : 'запрос не удался') );
            return;
        }
    }
```

Яваскрипт приложение крутится на localhost, yii на другом виртуальном хосте.

Answer (score 0):

Замените на:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password));
```